# Is there a problem when I use CSS-loader and url-loader?

Tags: webpack, css-loader, urlloader

when I use CSS-loader I set the options of url value false,then my url-loader won't handle the img where used in backgroud-url. The following is my setting,where is my problem?

css-loader config

```
exports.cssLoaders = function(options) {
  options = options || {};

  const cssLoader = {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: options.sourceMap,
      **url:false**,
    }
  };

  const postcssLoader = {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: options.sourceMap
    }
  };

  // generate loader string to be used with extract text plugin
  function generateLoaders(loader, loaderOptions) {
    const loaders = options.usePostCSS
      ? [cssLoader, postcssLoader]
      : [cssLoader];

    if (loader) {
      loaders.push({
        loader: loader + '-loader',
        options: Object.assign({}, loaderOptions, {
          sourceMap: options.sourceMap
        })
      });
    }

    // Extract CSS when that option is specified
    // (which is the case during production build)
    if (options.extract) {
      return ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: loaders,
        fallback: 'vue-style-loader',
        publicPath: '../../'
      });
    } else {
      return ['vue-style-loader'].concat(loaders);
    }
  }
```

url-loader config

```
  {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        exclude: [resolve('src/assets/icon')],
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          publicPath: publicAssetsPath,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          publicPath: publicAssetsPath,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          publicPath: '../../',
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
```

I cann't all use "publicPath: '../../", because The element img tag used "url" the path will become wrong. So is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you !